# How to set up a Singleton with ember-cli initializers?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

With the way that ember-cli provides injectors for DI, I have something like this in my `app/initializers/drupal-csrf-token.js` file:

```
export default {
  name: 'drupal-csrf-token',

  initialize: function(container, app) {
    app.inject('route', 'drupalCsrfToken', 'service:drupalCsrfToken');
    app.inject('controller', 'drupalCsrfToken', 'service:drupalCsrfToken');
  }
};
```

Normally, when you want a singleton with DI, you'd do something like this:

```
container.register('store:main', Store, { singleton: true });
```

However, I can't figure out where to stick the singleton flag on the initializer to make it stick.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You created the service using ember-cli?

Comment: Yes, I created the service with `ember g service DrupalCsrfToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside your initialize method, I believe:

```
  app.register('service:drupalCsrfToken', 'drupal-csrf-token', { singleton: true });
```

I do think singleton defaults to true though.

Comment: But wouldn't that register it twice? Since it seems to be magically registered already (the example works, it's just that I get a new instance every time I request it, which is not what I need.

Comment: Try the above but use singleton: false ?